# Socket.io / Node.js Message send to bad users

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sockets, socket.io

i am trying to do an message system (only conversation one user to one user) with mongoDB, node.js and socket.io all is working fine but when i send a message all the users receive it ... I will try to explain you better :

When 4 users are connected (2 in one chat and 2 other in an other chat)

> User 1 : Chat a
>
> User 2 : Chat a
>
> User 3 : Chat b
>
> User 4 : Chat b

When user 1 send a message : User 1, 2, 3, 4 see the message but only user 1 and 2 have the message save in database (so when i refresh all user : only user 1 and 2 have the message)

And here is the problem my messages are well saved but when someone send a message the socket send the message to all the users **connected**

Here is my code : server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

// Database Name
const dbName = 'Database';

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {

if (err)
    throw err;
console.log('MongoDB connected ...');

httpServer = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    console.log('This is a test');
    res.end('Hello World');
});

httpServer.listen(1337);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(httpServer);
var users = {};
var messages = [];

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    const collection = client.db(dbName).collection('MessageUser');

    var me = false;
    var friend = false;
    var conv = false;

    for(var k in users) {
        socket.emit('new_user', users[k]);
    }

    /**
     * Login
     */
    socket.on('login_chat', function (user) {
        me = user;
        friend = user.friend;
        conv = user.conv;
        console.log('New user : ', me.username, ' - id : ', me.id);
        users[me.id] = me;
        io.sockets.emit('new_user', me);
    });

    /**
     * Disconnect
     */
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        if (!me) {
            return false;
        }
        delete users[me.id];
        io.sockets.emit('disc_user', me);
    });

    /**
     * Message receive
     */
    socket.on('new_msg', function(message){
        if (message.message !== '') {
            message.user = me;
            date = new Date();
            message.h = date.getHours();
            message.m = date.getMinutes();
            message.y = date.getFullYear();
            message.m = date.getMonth();
            message.d = date.getDate();
            console.log(message);
            messages.push(message);
            msg = {};
            msg.content = message.message;
            msg.sendAt = new Date();
            msg.idTransmitter = me.id;
            msg.idReceiver = friend;
            msg.idConversation = conv;
            collection.insertOne(msg);
            console.log(msg.idReceiver, msg.idTransmitter, me);
            io.sockets.emit('new_msg', message, me, msg.idReceiver, msg.idTransmitter);
        }
    });
});
});
```

And client.js :

```
(function($){

var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1337');
var lastmsg = false;

startTchat = function(user_id, username, friend_id, conv_id) {
    socket.emit('login_chat', {
        id : user_id,
        username : username,
        friend : friend_id,
        conv : conv_id,
    })
};

/**
 * Error
 */
socket.on('error', function(err){
    alert(err);
});

/**
 * Messages
 */
$('#chat_form').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    socket.emit('new_msg', {message: $('#message').val() });
    $('#message').val('');
    $('#message').focus();
});

socket.on('new_msg', function(message, me, id_receiver, id_transmiter){
    if (me.id === id_receiver || me.id === id_transmiter) {
        if (lastmsg != message.user.id) {
            *(here i add a div with the msg)*
            lastmsg = message.user.id;
        } else {
            *(here too)*
        }
    }
});


/**
 * Login
 */
socket.on('new_user', function(user){
    *(here i add a div with new user)*
});


/**
 * Disconnect
 */
socket.on('disc_user', function(user){
    $('#' + user.id).remove();
})

})(jQuery);
```

My idea was this line : `if (me.id === id_receiver || me.id === id_transmiter)` (client.js line 33) but that seems doing nothing ...
So should i add something or maybe my condition is not good ...

ps : That's one of my first time using node, js and socket so i hope i explain well and ask me if you need more info or screenshots maybe :)

Comment: `socket.io` has the concept of [Rooms and Namespaces](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/). Why aren't you using them?

Comment: I did not know it existed I will try it let me 5Min

Comment: ok that's working thx :) if you want you can make a response and will put it to valid and i will also make a response for future people that will have same problem :)